# Textview alignment issue in Relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

When I have this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="nl.dylaan.deroosterapp.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/app_version"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

The text is in the center:

[image: in the ceneter]

But when I add a new text to it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="nl.dylaan.deroosterapp.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/app_version"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name_cap"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="35sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The new text is now in the center but the textView2 is not? I need to have it both in center:
[image]

Does anyone knows why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"` from your `RelativeLayout`, it's messing up with the rules.

And to align center all `View's` use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` on both `View's`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/app_version"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name_cap"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="35sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my code for textview2

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_version"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

It doesn't work because of the center horizontal layout